# Python session on Google Cloud Run automatically logs out

Tags: python, google-cloud-run

I am running a website on Google Cloud Run that I have written in Python. The site runs in a Docker image that uses `python:latest`. The code works, however after some time the user is logged out and I dont know why the session does not lasts.

**main.py:**

```
"""
Main
File: main.py
Updated: 23.10.2022 Ditlefsen
"""
import os

import flask
from flask import request, session

# Flask
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.urandom(12)


# - Index ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def __index():

    # Login user
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        request_form_global = request.form

        inp_username = request_form_global['inp_username']
        inp_password = request_form_global['inp_password']
        
        if inp_username == "hello" and inp_password == "world":
            session['logged_in'] = True
            

    if session.get('logged_in'):
        return "Welcome to the website", 200
    else:
        return "Access denied!", 304


# - Main ----------------------------------------------------------------------
def main(function_request: flask.wrappers.Request = None):
    app.run(debug=False, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
# Specify Python
FROM python:latest

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Open port
EXPOSE 8080

# Add Python script
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .


# Install dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Set Pythons path
ENV PYTHONPATH /app

# Run script
CMD [ "python", "./main.py" ]
```

**requirements.txt:**

```
cloud-sql-python-connector
flask
flask-cors
google-cloud-secret-manager
google
google-api-python-client
PyYAML
psycopg2-binary
pg8000
sqlalchemy==1.4.46
requests



flask-login
passlib
Werkzeug
```

What can I do to keep the user logged in?

Comment: How long is `after some time the user is logged out`? Remember, Cloud Run will terminate containers that are not processing requests. For us-central, I typically see 15 minutes of no requests and the container is terminated. Your code is bare bones. Many enhancements are required to make it production quality. Sessions, cookies, databases, etc are often necessary when running on stateless services such as Cloud Run. Write your code so that memory and storage can disappear at any time.

Comment: If you use storage solutions for sessions such as `Memcache` or `Redis`, expired sessions are automatically deleted. You may check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/getting-started/session-handling-with-firestore) for Handling sessions with `Firestore`. **Note:** this implementation is unsuitable for an app that can be served from multiple instances, because the session that is recorded in one instance might differ from other instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Does your user remain logged in if you test your code locally?
- What is the delay before being logged out?
  My guess is that your Google Cloud Run service is shut off after a while, depending on your subscription and/or parameters (see quotas [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas))